# Help with a simple debounce program on STM32

Tags: stm32, arm, debounce

I'm trying to write a simple debounce program on an STM32F4. Code as follows:

Initialization:

```
  RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN | RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN;
  RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;

  //Configure PB7 as output and PC13 as input pull-down
  GPIOB->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER7_0;
  GPIOC->PUPDR |= GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR13_1;

  //Configure Timer 2 for 20ms delay
  TIM2->PSC = 95;
  TIM2->ARR = 19999;
  TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_URS;
  TIM2->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE;
  TIM2->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;

  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
```

Main:

```
 while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      if (GPIOC->IDR & GPIO_IDR_ID13)
          TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;            //Enable Timer 2
  }
```

IRQ Handler:

```
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;                   // Reset Update Interrupt Flag on Timer 2 Status Register 
    if (GPIOC->IDR & GPIO_IDR_ID13)
    {
        GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_ODR_OD7;            // Toggle PB7
        TIM2->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN;             // Disable Timer 2
    }
}
```

I'm using a delay of 20ms on Timer 2 and toggling the LED on PB7. The LED does toggle, but it doesn't behave like a debounced switch and flickers as the LED turns on. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you expect the code to do then? Based on the code, as long as you press the button, it will keep turning on the timer, and the timer will keep toggling the LED.

Comment: @Justme I’d like it to behave like a normal debounced switch, toggle whenever pressed. I’ve read Ganssle’s algorithm for debouncing but I’m just confused as to how to go about it.

Comment: I think you should forget debouncing and timers for a while and concentrate on the program logic how to toggle the LED only when a button push is first detected, not toggle a LED while the button is being held pushed down.

Comment: @Justme I know how to toggle the LED when the button push is first detected, it’s just a matter of removing all the timer stuff and replacing `TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN` with `GPIOB->ODR ^= GPIO_ODR_OD7`. That’s worked for me. I want to learn how to debounce the switch so that I won’t see any ripple on the output.

Comment: You need an extra variable for your code to 'remember' if it's already toggled the LED for the current button-press so that it doesn't just continuously toggle. If you use a `bool`, then only toggle the LED in the ISR if it's `false`, and then immediately set it to `true`. Only set it back to `false` when you see that the button has been released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make 2  global variables called `tick` and `previousTick`, or whatever you want, and inside the timer ISR increment the `tick` variable by 1. then check if the difference between this `tick` and `previoustick` is larger than a value of your choice then consider the button debounced, otherwise if the difference of this `tick` and `previousTick` is not large enough then that means your button has bounced.  At the end of ISR  set `previousTick = tick`.

Psuedo code:

```
   //GLOBALS
   uint32_t tick = 0 ; 
   uint32_t previousTick = 0 ; 
           
   timerInterrupt()
   {
       tick++;
       if( (tick - previousTick) > 5 ) 
           // using your 20ms this means  100ms spread.
           // then *do some stuff here because button has been deboucned.*
       else 
           //*do nothing or something else here since button has been clicked too rapidly  or is boucning*
        
       ClearInterrupts();
       previousTick = tick;
   }
```

Comment: These variables need to be declared as volatile or the compiler might make strange assumptions during optimization. Anyway, there's likely no good reason for not sticking the debounce code itself inside the timer ISR and store the debounced result in a variable instead.